# Como guardar la variable $_SESSION en cada pagina luego de logear un usuario?

Tags: php, mysql, session

Tengo las paginas **user.php**, **header.php** y **indexph.php**. Luego de logear puedo mostrar el nombre de mi usuario en el header, pero una vez que avanzo a otra pagina se borra la variable de mi header, ya que este esta dentro de un "isset" que funciona solo cuando el usuario clickea en "Log in", ahora lo que necesito es que se mantenga en el header en todas las paginas una vez ingresado al sistema, ya que el header lo invoco en las paginas por medio de "required_once('header.php')" y una vez el usuario desloguea borrar esta variable, ocultarla o destruirla. Aca dejo parte de mi codigo...

**user.php(no todo)**

```
<?php include("conexion.php");
  require_once("header.php") ?>
 <form action="" method="POST" id="loginform">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Usuario" name="usuar">
 <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" name="pw">
 <button type="submit" class="btn" name="logi">Login</button>
 <a href="">Olvidaste la contraseña?</a>
 </form>
?>
```

**header.php(invocado por required_once)**

```
<?php
include("conexion.php");
if(isset($_POST['logi'])){
  $u=$_POST["usuar"];
  $c=$_POST["pw"];

  $sql="SELECT * FROM usuario
  WHERE usuario='".$u."' AND contr='".$c."' ";

  $res=mysql_query($sql,$con);
  $can=mysql_num_rows($res);
  $b=mysql_fetch_array($res);

  if($can == 1)
  {
  $session = array(
    "connected" =>True,
    "id_usuario" => $u,
         );
  $_SESSION["logged"] = $session;
  echo "Login OK by ".$u;
  echo "<form action='logout.php' method='POST'>";
  echo "<button type='submit' name='logo'>Logout</button>";
  echo "</form>";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Login Failed";
  }

  }

  ?>

  <header id="header">
  <div class="navbar">
  <nav>
        <ul id="menuitems">
            <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="indexph.php">Productos</a></li>
            <li><a href="añadir.html">Añadir</a></li>
            <li><a href="detalle productos.html">D.P&#9760;</a></li>
            <li><a href="account.html">Cuenta</a></li>
        </ul> 
  </nav>

        <a href="kart.php" class="nav-item nav-link active">
        <img src="../img/cart.png" width="50px" height="50px">
        </a>
        <!---aca quisiera mostrar el nombre de usuario y que aparezca en todas las paginas cuando uso "required_once('header.php')---->
   </div>
  </header>
```

Quiero saber como en cada pagina llamar a "$_SESSION["logged"]" una vez haya iniciado sesion, el tema es que en la pagina se tiene que poder navegar sin iniciar sesion, entonces no quiero llamar al session_start(); en cada php, la idea es que se llame solo luego de logear en el sistema EN EL HEADER para yo poder mostrar quien ha ingresado al sistea..

```
<?php

if(isset($_SESSION["logged"]) and $_SESSION["logged"]["connected"] == True)
{
    //esto funciona solo si antes llamo a session_start();
}
else
{
    $_SESSION["logged"]=session_destroy();//algo asi se me ocurria pero no funciona
}

?>
```

El problema claramente esta en el header, ya que yo quiero que siempre el nombre del usuario se mantenga ahi, y yo llamarlo en cual pagina sea que este luego de haber ingresado al sistema, ya que una vez que avanzo a indexph.php se pierde la variable y no puedo mostrar el nombre del usuario que ingreso...

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: `session_start()` no inicia sesión en tu sistema, solo inicia una sessión de PHP (que es muy distinto) o continua una anterior si ya existia(). Si o si debes llamar a session_start() en cada página.

Comment: Claro, yo llamo a session_start() por ejemplo en mi header solo quiero poner una condicion de que cuando el usuario ya haya ingresado la variable $_SESSION["logged"]["connected"]=>"True" y cuando no haya ingresado, o haya deslogeado sea un False..

Answer (score 0):

Deberías intentar algo así:

```
session_start();
//Suponiendo que tu if está bien y funciona
if(isset($_SESSION["logged"]) and $_SESSION["logged"]["connected"] == True) {
    //** HACE LO QUE TIENE QUE HACER 
} else {
    $_SESSION["logged"] = "";
}
```

Como ya te dijeron líneas arriba, debes utilizar el `session_start()` siempre al inicio de cada archivo **PHP** (Iniciar una nueva sesión o reanudar la existente).
Si el usuario está logueado el `$_SESSION["logged"]` mostrará al usuario, pero si no está logueado el `$_SESSION["logged"]` no mostrará nada y seguirá funcionando como quieres que sea.

El `session_destroy()` debes invocarlo cuando vas a desloguear a tu usuario.

Comment: Gracias por responder! lo puse y funciono, luego de que el usuario entra y entra al if, muestro el nombre del usuario y pongo un form para que el usuario desloguee, aqui llamo a "logout.php" que solo hace esto: <?php session_destroy();
 header('location: indexph.php'); ?> aqui deberia colocar lo que me indicaste arriba ? osea esto? --> $_SESSION["logged"] = "";